# Application should have 3 tiers

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I am writing a small application in WPF. It allows me to save and read data from db. It has 3 tiers (Business logic, Presentation layer, and Data Access). I use database-first approach and Entity Framework has generated a model for me.

My question is where I should store my .edmx generated model?

If I put it in the Data Access I will need to write some duplicate code in my Business logic, and if I put this model in the Business Logic then what should I store in the Data Access tier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Entity Framework model most logically belongs in the data access layer, I believe.  I've typically used a Data Service wrapper on top of EF, then you can initiate your transactions, perform business logic validation, etc. at or above that layer.  Some additional info on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646358/entity-framework-in-a-layered-architecture).

There is an interesting slide on EF and the data access layer [here](http://www.slideshare.net/wwegner/adonet-entity-framework-your-data-access-layer).